# In NebulaGraph Database, How to resolve the error edge conflict or vertex conflict?

Tags: nebula-graph

What does the conflict mean in the Nebula Graph of this error `edge conflict`?

Which process meet this error when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Nebula Graph may return such errors when the Storage service receives multiple requests to insert or update the same vertex or edge within milliseconds. Try the failed requests again later.